# Can sigqueue be used with pthreads?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, posix

Can sigqueue be used instead of [`pthread_kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) in multi-threading , as I want to use the (`const union sigval value`) in sigqueue . I don't have [`pthread_sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigqueue.3.html) in my linux.

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux it is possible to pull a thread specific `pid_t` from the kernel using the [`gettid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) system call, which then could be used together with [`sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigqueue.3.html). This however is Linux specifiy and highly unportable.

As `gettid()` mostly likely is not available via your Linux' libc you might like to use the following code to implement it:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t gettid(void) 
{
  return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}
```